# .tfignore not working on VS 2015 RC 3

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfignore

I tried to ignore some folders and prevent them to check-in in TFS, I read here about a bug on VS 2015 but seems to be fixed in RC3, well not for me, the only thing ignored by the TFS is the .tfignore file.

I have created it on the root solution folder and the content looks as follow:

```
\packages
\.fake
\.paket
\.vs
```

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try without \ and add * for files :

```
*.fake
*.paket
*.vs
packages
```

Comment: It is finally working, I have to say that the .fake .paket and .vs are folders, but looks like taking out the '\' make the trick, also I have tried with files and working like champ.

Thanks you!